# Obspy to plot obspy.imaging.mopad_wrapper.Beach object to PNG

Tags: python, plot

I haven't been able to find anywhere a simple example on how to plot a moment tensor to a png file. I have been reading this: [obspy tensor example page](http://docs.obspy.org/packages/obspy.imaging.html)

The simple example shows how to generate the tensor but none of them show how to just plot a simple tensor to a file. Also the parts that do show how to make it output stuff to a file do not refer to the tensor types of objects. If anyone could explain how to put the tensor, just the tensor ( no axes no nothing else ) into a png file i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

just use the `outfile` argument as listed in http://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.imaging.beachball.Beachball.html

```
from obspy.imaging.beachball import Beachball
mt = [-2.39, 1.04, 1.35, 0.57, -2.94, -0.94]
Beachball(mt, outfile="test.png")
```